# How do you fix a broken function, toAscii, failing due to an iconv line?

Tags: php

I lost track of where I found it, googled and didn't find the obvious source. I have a simple CMS with a function to create a page title to a user friendly url. It generally works.

The page title might contain French, German or other accented characters.

I am moving a site from a VestCP control panel to common cPanel and there it fails. The function:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF8');
function toAscii($str, $replace=array(), $delimiter='-') {
 if( !empty($replace) ) { $str = str_replace((array)$replace, ' ', $str); }
  $data = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $str);
  $data = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\/_|+ -]/", '', $data);
  $data = strtolower(trim($data, '-'));
  $data = preg_replace("/[\/_|+ -]+/", $delimiter, $data);
  $data = strtolower(trim($data, '-'));
  return $data;
}
```

It errors out as follows on the iconv line:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function iconv() in /home/$account/public_html/toAscii.php on line 13
```

By commenting out that line and changing the $str variable I can get it to work. However I would like to understand why it fails with different hosting, control panel, what I cam losing without iconv and if there is a workaround.

Comment: what php version do yo u run?

Comment: both hosts are running 5.6.4 on CentOS but different control panels.

Comment: Ask your hoster if the deliberately compiled PHP without iconv support? https://www.php.net/manual/en/iconv.installation.php

Comment: I doubt if they know without digging. VestaCP is the open source one that you download and install - on that host it works. The one set with common cPanel is the one that fails. Seems backwards to me. It seemed a little curious to me that both run php 5.6.4 - or is that default with CentOS? The more important question though is what do I lose by losing iconv and is there a replacement?